# Can I configure a keyboard shortcut to input a specific string while typing?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I use c++ often and need to type the "->" symbol quite a lot.

Because of my german keyboard, I have to first type the dash "-" and then press the FN+SHIFT+L to get the ">" which is quite an annoying combination.

I was just wondering if there was a way to configure a shortcut for example FN+ö or ALTGRP+ö (or some other key that I'm not using) to type "->" automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#compose) and create an `~/.XCompose` file with for instance this line:

```
<Multi_key> <r> <a> : "->"  # RIGHT ARROW
```

Next time you log in you should be able to press <kbd>Compose</kbd> followed by <kbd>R</kbd> followed by <kbd>A</kbd> to get **->**. Tested in gnome-terminal and gedit.

Comment: I have one concern the arrow operator `->` is too special to put it. My Terminal or application doesn't print these characters in this order. I tried `xdotool type "->"` and `xclip` paste from a file, these worked on Terminal but not as a shortcut.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka: Right, I have the same concern. The source from where I got the idea mentioned that compose is actually intended for single unicode characters, while this is a string with two characters. The consequence is that you can't expect it to work in all applications. But when I tested successfully in both gedit and gnome-terminal, i decided to provide an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's enough for me if it works with VS Code. If I want the shortcut to be `Alt + l` and my compose key is Alt by default, then I have to write `<Multi_key> <l> : "->"`? If this is correct, then it didn't work for me neither in a terminal nor in gedit.

Comment: @Andrew.M: It's not a shortcut, it's a compose sequence, and I think it needs to be at least two characters.